# Is it possible to import file from local machine to Jenkins server during start of the build

Tags: jenkins, automation

Currently I have my whole automation source code (Script and test data) in Jenkins server and whenever I want to change my test data, I need to go to the Jenkins server machine and changing it .

The problem is if I want to change the test data, I need to wait for long time for my access from the admin team. Also I have huge number of test data in my project so I am not interested in creating Jenkins project with Parameter Builds. So if there any option available in Jenkins to import files (excel) before build then that would we helpful.

Please consider as a priority one.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to transfer files to Jenkins server is to use a version control system like git or subversion:

1. Commit files to version control system
2. Configure Jenkins job to detect change in the version control system and check out work directory for the build or test

If your files are so big they cannot fit into a version control system (some of them do not perform well with files in the gigabyte range), you could use a shared disk drive which you have permission to write to.